# Autofill Excel Cells using a list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been trying to make an excel in which I record prices. My problem is that I have a variaty of goods and sellers. For that reason i would like when i enter the name of a seller to be autocompleted from excel or in case the name does not exist to be saved in a column and next to the name at the corresponding date the price of the good to be stored.

For example i go to sheet "Varnish - Sell" and I type Tyrbognoma, i would like excel to recognize the name automaticaly and insert it in column A and at the date we have today to ask me to insert the price.

I do realise that it may sound complicated what i am asking so i am attaching my excel in order to get a better picture of what i ask for.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jslpphjr0kru4ei/Market.xlsx?dl=0

P.S : Ignore the macros which already exist in this file

Thank you for your time everyone

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You have mistaken this for a service site where we will do the work. On the contrary, this is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my request. I didnt ask you to do the work. What i ask for is advice or in otherword the know-how. What I ve tried so far is the google microsft and your site. Due to the nature of my question whenever i use the words autofill or similar phrase i get misleaded (i think) by a different function of the excel. Unfortunately i am not a professional so i dont know how to work this problem around and that is the reason i am asking for help. If this is not the place for suggestion or similar solutions for such a problem i apologize and i kindly request to delete my post.

Comment: PS : In case that you think this is something that i am going to be financialy benefit, I inform you that the whole excel refers to a game i am interested to make some financial conclusions.

Comment: Maybe the word you're looking for is auto-complete.

Comment: I found yesterday an article relative to the auto-complete function i am looking for but i still havent figured out how to solve my problem.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ecef0395-344b-4020-a606-d23efcb0c7d8/auto-complete-cells-from-another-sheet-or-section?forum=excel

Here they say that all the words to be autocompleted, in my case names need to be all at the same column. Unfortunately thats not my case. I was thinking somehow to make excel read all the columns with names in the different sheets and use them somehow. But I havent done any progress yet

Comment: Considering you have not asked a single question, it reads like you are placing an order, it makes it difficult to answer you. Also, due to risks of viruses and malware, most people will not download your file. So, this leaves you will having to explain your question clearly, completely and provide examples of how your data is laid out. It is difficult to help when we don't know what version of Excel you are using and how the data is entered. Please use the **[edit]** feature to update your question so people don't have to read comments to figure out what is going on.